# Eclipse preferences displays android tab twice

Tags: android, eclipse-neon

I am using eclipse neon to make an android project. When I start importing an existing project it shows me two android options.So I went to preferences of eclipse it is also showing me android tab twice. both the tabs show same path of android sdk. Here i am attaching screenshot of my preferences window. please tell me how to get the android tab only once.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have two DDMS plugins installed.
-Go to your eclipse\plugins folder
-search DDMS
-if more than one shows up, delete one of them.
-restart eclipse

I had the same issue and that is what fixed it for me.

Comment: Hi JWCode, I found 2 DDMS one is andmore ddms and another is com.android.ide eclipse ddms which one should i delete?

Comment: Its really up to you on with one. I deleted the "andmore" DDMS since it was an add on. "com.android.ide" is part Eclipse Android IDE when you install it.

Comment: thank you very much it worked. I deleted com.android.ide eclipse ddms. my project is working now

Comment: Andmore is not an "add on", it's the successor to ADT which is no longer supported by Google. https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/andmore-development-tools-android%E2%84%A2

Comment: Same here, just deleted com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_25.2.5.3567187.jar inside \eclipse\plugins\. Note : use Eclipse distribuded as zip, not with windows installer (plugins dir is empty)